# Webpack errors after build when importing markdown files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, markdown

I setup a webpack-react-redux isomorphic app.

Also I use webpack-dev-server for development and webpack to build javascript & css files.

I want to use markdown-loader for webpack to transform markdown to html.

So I installed the markdown-loader and added it to the dev.config.webpack & the production.config.webpack file.

Now for the development server it works fine, it will import README.md and transform it to html. 
When building the app to production, start it up and refresh in my browser it throws a error about not able to import './README.md';

So my question; how can I import a markdown file and use contents, when building my app for production?

Thnx in advance..!